# Webpack concat output js file to wrap it in a library?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, webpack-dev-server

I need to concat a webpack output with other files, like `pre.js + bundle.js(the webpack output file) + after.js`. I've tried the webpack concat plugin and also combining webpack with gulp, but I just can't figure out how to get the output file and pipeline it to concat task. The purpose of this is to wrap the output in a custom library.

**webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        ['es2015', {modules: false}]
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }
    ]},
     plugins: [
        new ConcatPlugin({
            useHash: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            name: 'flxeible',
            fileName: '[name].bundle.js',
            filesToConcat: ['pre.js','dist/bundle.js','after.js']
        })
    ]
};
```

This concatenates the `bundle.js` that's been already been built, not the one that's being generated and updated by the webpack dev server.

**using gulp**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util')
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js')

gulp.task('default', [ "webpack-dev-server"])

var myDevConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig);

gulp.task("webpack-dev-server", function(callback){

    new WebpackDevServer(webpack(myDevConfig), {
        stats: {
            colors: true
        }
    }).listen(8080, "localhost", function(err){
         if(err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
         gutil.log("[webpack-dev-server]", 
         "http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/index.html");
     })
})
```

in the second case, not sure how to get the webpack output in gulp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `gulp` solely to run the `webpack-dev-server`? This is not necessary: https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server

Without knowing the content+purpose of `pre.js` and `after.js`, it's hard to give good advice. You might want to adapt the [BannerPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/BannerPlugin.js) to also output a footer=`after.js`, or configure webpack to [generate multiple targets](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#multiple-targets) (first `dist/bundle.js`, and `pre.js`+`dist/bundle.js`+`after.js` afterwards), or check the [various ways for shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/), or combine the tree files to a new entry file via three subsequent imports (`import 'pre.js'; import 'bundle.js'; import 'after.js'`). Good luck.